# Validation for radio buttons and drop down

Tags: javascript, php, html

how do I create a validation for my radio buttons and drop down box? Do I need to create a `<script>` function on top?

```
<tr> 
    <td class="alt"><label for="period"><b>Transaction Period:</b> </label></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="period" value="current">Current Month<br>
        <input type="radio" name="period" value="current_first">Last 1 Month and Current Month<br>
        <input type="radio" name="period" value="current_second">Last 2 Months and Current Month</td>          
</tr>
    <td class="alt"><label for="type"><b>Type: </b></label></td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="both">Credit and Debit<br>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="credit">Credit Only<br>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="debit">Debit Only 
    </td>
<tr>
    <td class="alt"><label for="sort"><b>Sort According To: </b></label></td>
    <td> <select name="sort">
            <option value="latest">Latest Transaction First</option>
            <option value="earliest">Earliest Transaction First</option>
              <option value="codes">Transaction Codes</option>
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'validation' exactly? Just a test to see if an input has been selected?

Comment: @Joeytje50 yes, exactly. User will have to select one option from every label before they will be allowed to submit to next page. Pop up alert if user did not complete the form.

Comment: you can auto select one, that way the user is bound to have at least 1 active

Comment: Have you googled it?  Have you made any attempt at all?http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: Im not sure radio buttons work for this @RickS

Comment: I have tried to use if ($period == null) { echo "Please select one option"; } etc. but it doesnt work @RickS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight invalid inputs, use the [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) pseudo-class. This won't work in [older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid#Browser_compatibility), but newer browsers do all support using it on inputs. For the inputs, you will have to add the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute, and you'll need to add a tag around their label (for example a `<span>`) for this to work though:

**New HTML code:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="alt">
            <label for="period"><b>Transaction Period:</b> 
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" required name="period" value="current"><span>Current Month</span>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" required name="period" value="current_first"><span>Last 1 Month and Current Month</span>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" required name="period" value="current_second"><span>Last 2 Months and Current Month</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <td class="alt">
        <label for="type"><b>Type: </b>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" required name="type" value="both"><span>Credit and Debit</span>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" required name="type" value="credit"><span>Credit Only</span>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" required name="type" value="debit"><span>Debit Only </span>

    </td>
    <tr>
        <td class="alt">
            <label for="sort"><b>Sort According To: </b>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="sort" required>
                <option value="" selected disabled>Please select an option</option>
                <option value="latest">Latest Transaction First</option>
                <option value="earliest">Earliest Transaction First</option>
                <option value="codes">Transaction Codes</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
input:invalid + span {
    background:#F99;
}
select:invalid {
    color:#F55;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TJ9n3/).

### How this pseudo-class works

This `:invalid` pseudo-class will select an input element if it:

- has a specific value, such as `type="number"`, and the entered input does not meet that specific input type's value
- has no assigned value, such as a `<select>` having an empty-valued option selected, or radio inputs not having one of the radio buttons it shares its name with selected
- the input has an attribute such as `pattern` or `max` defined, and the input does not match the entered pattern, or exceeds the maximum value.

If any of the inputs is still `:invalid`, the form won't be submitted, even when pressing the submit button. ([simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/4tW6y/))

Comment: Will this prevent a form from being submitted?